# Why ListStyle plugin doesn't show up in my CKEditor in Django website?

Tags: django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

[image: the ckeditor config used]

As seen here, I have two more extraPlugins, which do show up on the Website. The problem is liststyle only. Am I supposed to add anything to the toolbar list? 'NumberedList' and 'BulletedList' are already there, and I thought liststyle was supposed to override them.

[image: The sources as shown in chrome devtools]

As you can see, the liststyle is again not seen here, although field and codesnippet are. I have also downloaded the plugin dependencies for liststyle. Is there anything else I need to do?